# Stuck within a For Each Loop - endlessly searching for matches

Tags: excel, foreach, vba

I'm new to VBA - totally foreign language, doing my best to understand.

I am trying to write a piece of code which will help me colour-code items in one worksheet based on the Interior Color format of cells in a table in another worksheet.  I have achieved it on a basic level but come unstuck when the value of a cell for colour-coding fails to match any of the values in the table in Sheet2.  Ideally what I want it to do in this instance is simply move on to the cell 1 row down and continue looping but what actually happens is it goes round and round the table in Sheet2 endlessly looking for a match.  I have tried various Else and ElseIf statements to try and stop this but none of them result in the desired outcome.  The code I have written (badly, I'm sure) is below:

---

```
Sub Colour_Code_Cells()

    Dim xlRange As Range
    Dim xlCell As Range
    Dim xlSheet As Worksheet
    Dim formatSheet As Worksheet
    Dim formatRange As Range
    Dim formatCell As Range

        Set xlSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("colourcode")
        Set xlRange = xlSheet.Range("A1:A10")
        Set formatSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        Set formatCell = formatSheet.Range("A2")

            formatCell.Activate

            Do Until Selection.Value = ""

                For Each xlCell In xlRange

                        If xlCell.Value = ActiveCell.Value Then
                        ActiveCell.Interior.Color = xlCell.Interior.Color
                        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select

                        End If

                Next xlCell

            Loop


End Sub
```

---

Any constructive tips would be most gratefully received.  How do you tell it to stop looking at each Next xlCell if it has already looked once???

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is the you have the `ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select` inside the If statement, so if it does not find a match in the `xlRange` it will not move to the next cell and keep checking the same cell.  Thus an endless loop.

Select and Activate will slow down the code and are not usually needed and should be avoided.

A small refactor of the code will make it quicker and more reliable.

This will do it with one loop using match to find the match:

```
Sub Colour_Code_Cells()

    Dim xlRange As Range
    Dim xlCell As Range
    Dim xlSheet As Worksheet
    Dim formatSheet As Worksheet
    Dim formatRange As Range
    Dim formatCell As Range
    Dim t As Long

    Set xlSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("colourcode")
    Set xlRange = xlSheet.Range("A1:A10")
    Set formatSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    With formatSheet
        For Each formatCell In .Range("A2", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
            t = 0
            On Error Resume Next
            t = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(formatCell, xlRange, 0)
            On Error GoTo 0

            If t > 0 Then
                formatCell.Interior.Color = xlRange(t).Interior.Color
            End If
        Next formatCell
    End With


End Sub
```

Comment: Scott thank you so much that works perfectly.  I will probably be spending my morning making sure I understand exactly what each of those instructions within the For Each command is actually doing - good to be able to learn something knowing it works rather than repeated trial and error for a change :)

Comment: @NTen please mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer